# Image loading small in size when loaded from URL in Android

Tags: android, url, imageview

I have a requirement of loading an Image from a URL in my Android application

For this I created an ImageView in my layout. Following is the Imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MyImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">          
</ImageView>
```

And then in my code I use the following to load the image in this ImageView

```
ImageView bmImage = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.MyImage);
String urldisplay = urls[0];
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
try {
    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

bmImage.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
```

The image that is lying on my URL path is of size 320 X 50. But very strange, when the image is shown in the ImageView, the size becomes very small, almost half the width and height

I have tried a lot but no solution. Can anybody help please?

Comment: What is the parent of this ImageView in your layout? Have you tried setting the `scaleType` attribute for the ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting bitmap pixels and expecting device pixels

Try to get the density of the screen then set the width/height so it stretches accordingly, like this:

```
ImageView bmImage = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.MyImage);
String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 bmImage.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
 if(mIcon11 != null){
   int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mIcon11.getWidth(), this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mIcon11.getHeight(), this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

   bmImage.setMinimumWidth(width);
   bmImage.setMinimumHeight(height);
 }
```

Comment: One more help please, I a wanting the banner to be centred on the screen, but not working out. Though I have given the layout as center_horizontal. The banner is coming left aligned with the screen

Comment: To center, make sure you use gravity and layout_gravity appropriately.

Comment: Please see I have already given gravity and layout_gravity as "center_horizontal" but not working out

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    </ImageView>

Answer (score 0):

use this
[image loading library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
 and make sure to include this configuration in the DisplayImageOptions `imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)`